# PHP - intellisense for an object after calling PDOStatement::fetchObject()

Tags: php, pdo

Does anyone know how I can get intellisense to detect member variables of my player object after it has been assigned data from fetchObject().

Example

```
class Player {
    public $playerID;
    public $playerEXP;
}

//PDO connection already established
//Sql prepared, bind & execute complete.

$player = new Player();

$player = $stmt->fetchObject("Player");
```

when typing $player-> I would like to see member variables of Player(), instead of PDO methods,
Is there a way to cast $player as a Player() Object?

Comment: An annotation always works.

Comment: Thank you, could you please give me an example of how annotations would work for my example?

Comment: I think, but it's just a guess, that YCS means that you left out most of your code and simply state, in a comment (= annotation), that everything just works fine, no worry. Clearly it didn't because your `fetchObject()` returns something you don't expect.

Comment: The usual phpdoc annotation var \Player

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ah, I get it now, nerotech is talking about what appears in the IDE when typing.

Comment: Great, Thanks. /* @var $player Player */ works.

Comment: How about annotations on a public member variable? e.g. /* @var $this->somevariable Object */ doesn't work.

Comment: this can be set right in the class definition, public Player $somevariable;

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4 and just wanted to mention that declaring $player type as Player also works. i.e.  public Player $somevariable; when using member variables.